# Regarding the acceleration of centre of mass of a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

I came across the following question today:

> [image]

The answers are options (B),(D). I was having a hard time visualizing how acceleration of point A is going to be horizontal and if it is going to be towards right or left, hence, I decided to mathematically derive the acceleration expressions to prove it. But, I got stuck few times, while, other times I got different results using different equations.

Also, although I know that acceleration of the centre of mass of rod is going to be vertically downwards initially ${( a(COM) = g - T/m )}$, I have a little confusion here. If I start analyzing the motion (torque-wise) of the rod about point A, the acceleration of COM of the rod seems to be tangential rather than vertically down. So even for this case, I am unable to be certain about the tendency of the motion of the rod.

I think I would be able to visualize the scene better via mathematical derivation. It would also help me analyze where I was going wrong in the equations that I wrote.

Could someone please derive mathematically the accelerations of both, the COM of the rod, and point A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fallacy in your analysis of motion about A using torque is that, A itself is an accelerated point, so if you want to analyze the motion about it you should add a pseudo torque due to a pseudo force passing through the COM. This pseudo force would be given by $\mathbf F=-m\mathbf a$ where $\mathbf F$ is the pseudo force, $m$ is mass of Rod and $\mathbf a$ is acceleration of point A.
Since this calculation could be a little cumbersome, it is most prudent to analyze the situation with respect to COM only. As you yourself stated, the acceleration of the COM would be in the vertical direction. Moreover, the rod has an angular acceleration of $\alpha$, due to torque from tension. Also, note that the locus of A is a circle, and since at $t=0$ velocity of A is $0$, that means the centripetal acceleration at this point, which is in the vertical direction, must be $0$. This much information is enough to solve your question, but if you wish to calculate the acceleration, you should write three equations:

1.Equation of torque about COM

2.Equation of force

3.Vertical acceleration of point A is $0$, due to reasons stated.

Edit:
Since you needed help with the workout, here it is:
Let us assume the rod to be making an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. Then:
$\frac {ml^2}{12}\alpha=T\frac l2 \cos(\theta)...(1)$

$ma=mg-T...(2)$

$a=\frac {\alpha l}{2} \cos(\theta)...(3)$

Solve these to get your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; I have a little doubt here - Isn't the COM also accelerating, so why aren't we considering pseudo torque about it as well;  I think I have a sort of unclarity in certain parts of the concept itself (I am usually able to solve rotation questions, but have been stuck on this one for so long now), as even after writing the three equations, I am not able to proceed with certainty. It'd be very helpful if you could please show the steps for finding the accelerations

Comment: Yes, the com is accelerating, but any pseudo force due to that would pass through com itself, hence you see no torque for that at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally realized where I was going wrong - It was the third equation the whole time. I was constantly missing out the 'cosθ' in a, i.e., I was writing a = α(l/2); This brings me to a doubt (something I have been confused by earlier too) - how did you determine that a = α(l/2)cosθ and not acosθ = α(l/2)

Comment: Because, as I said, the centripetal acceleration is $0$, which is directed along the vertical. So the vertical components should cancel.

Comment: Oh alright, now I got it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint, as it might be a homework question:

Imagine what the system would look like a short time later, when presumably $B$ has swung down from where it starts and is more or less underneath $A$.

$B$ would then be in motion (to the left), if you just picture this happening, it seems that three options can be eliminated.